# How to get the following isomorphism by anti-isomorphism?

Tags: modules, representation-theory

Let $A$, be a finite dimension algebra over a field K. $fA$ is a projective-injective right $A$-module, for some idempotent $f \in A$. So, $D(fA) \cong Ae$ for some idempotent $e \in A$.

I have seen in a place, that " $$fAf \cong End_{A^{op}}(fA) \cong End_A(D(fA))^{op} \cong End_A(Ae)^{op} \cong eAe$$

Via these isomorphisms, the right $eAe$-module $Ae$ becomes a right $fAf$-module."

I know that, $End_A(Ae)\cong eAe$ and $eAe$ is anti-isomorphic to $eAe^{op}$ as algebras, so who can tell me how to get the last isomorphism?

Comment: What does $D(fA)$ mean?  Do you mean take the dual as a vector space to get a right module?

Comment: @freeRmodule $D=Hom_K(-,K)$ is the dual. And it maps a right module to a left module.

Comment: If you use left modules then the last iso is automatic I guess.

Comment: @Mare I have checked it. You are right. $End_A(Ae) \cong eAe^{op}$ as left $A$-module. Thank you.